# why do I get segmentation fault when calling printf in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, printf

I'm trying to print a string char by char, by calling the printf in assembly code,, but i get segmentation fault after printing the first char, and I can't understand why is that happening,, can someone help please ??

```
section .rodata
lc:
    DB  "%c", 10, 0

section .text
    align 16
    global my_func
    extern printf

my_func:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    ; Entry code - set up ebp and esp
    pusha           ; Save registers

    mov ecx, dword [ebp+8]  ; Get argument (pointer to string)

incr:   
    cmp byte [ecx], 0
    jz end

    movzx eax, byte [ecx]
    push eax
    push lc
    call printf
    add esp, 8

    inc ecx
    jmp incr

end:    
    popa            ; Restore registers
    mov esp, ebp    ; Function exit code
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are _caller-saved_ registers. So you shouldn't rely on the values of any of those registers to be preserved across a function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're calling the `printf` in the C-runtime. I don't believe that C functions are required to preserve the values of registers across calls so ECX is probably getting clobbered by the call.